# Striped Table using with or without bootstrap

Tags: css

How can I implement striped datarows in my table?

```
.dataTable tbody tr.odd{background-color:#000000}
.dataTable tbody tr.even{background-color:#ffffff}
```

That code doesnt work for me.
And if i use materialize the blade simply ruined.

Masters please help.

> Blockquote
>       @if($cat!=null)
>       
>       
>           
>               Audit Procedure
>               
>               Work Done
>           
>       
>       @else

```
@endif
@if($cat!=null)
    @foreach($dataArray as $val)
    <tr class="dataTable">
        <td class="complianceTD">{{$val[0]}}</td>
        <td class="complianceTD_2">{{$val[1]}}</td>
        <td class="complianceTD_3">{{$val[2]}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    @foreach($dataArray as $val)
    <tr>
        <td class="complianceTD2"><div class="textContent">{{$val[0]}}</div></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: If your using bootstrap have you tried there striped rows for tables: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-striped

Comment: Seems to be working. Share your HTML, might give a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have :

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
         <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
         <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
         <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
         <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
         <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
         <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you can use :

```
 table tr:nth-child(odd) td{ background-color:#000000; }  
 table tr:nth-child(even) td{ background-color:#ffffff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to make use of the :nth-child().
Look at the code snipped, you have more possibilites on how to color your rows depending on the formula you use as parameter.

```css
.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: #CCC;    
}

.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #777;    
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
    <th>header 5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 1, Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 1, Col 4</td>
      <td>Row 1, Col 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 2, Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 2, Col 4</td>
      <td>Row 2, Col 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 3, Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 3, Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 3, Col 4</td>
      <td>Row 3, Col 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 4, Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 4, Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 4, Col 4</td>
      <td>Row 4, Col 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 5, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 5, Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 5, Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 5, Col 4</td>
      <td>Row 5, Col 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: green;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5tbhkew/

Answer (score 0):

You should use td for table content, but also depends on your html on how you construct your table

```
.dataTable tbody td.odd {
    background-color:#000000
}
.dataTable tbody td.even {
    background-color:#ffffff
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Im new in stackoverflow that is why the format is quiet unacceptable.